# Basic GUI for shell commands with Python Tk threading and os.system calls

Tags: python, shell, command-line, tk-toolkit

I'm doing a basic GUI to provide some user feedback after some shell commands, a little interface for a shell script really.

Showing a TK window, waiting for a os.system call to complete and updating the TK window multiple times, after each os.system call.

How does threading work with tk?

That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a basic example of what I did, with credit to Constantinius for pointing out that Thread works with Tk!

```
import sys, thread
from Tkinter import *
from os import system as run
from time import sleep

r = Tk()
r.title('Remote Support')
t = StringVar()
t.set('Completing Remote Support Initalisation         ')
l = Label(r,  textvariable=t).pack() 
def quit():
    #do cleanup if any
    r.destroy()
but = Button(r, text='Stop Remote Support', command=quit)
but.pack(side=LEFT)

def d():
    sleep(2)
    t.set('Completing Remote Support Initalisation, downloading, please wait         ')
    run('sleep 5') #test shell command
    t.set('Preparing to run download, please wait         ')
    run('sleep 5')
    t.set("OK thanks! Remote Support will now close         ")
    sleep(2)
    quit()

sleep(2)
thread.start_new_thread(d,())
r.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard threading library should be perfectly okay if you run it with Tk. [This](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm) source says, that you should just let the main thread run the gui and create threads for your `os.system()` calls.

You could write an abstraction like this which updates your GUI upon finishing the task:

```
def worker_thread(gui, task):
    if os.system(str(task)) != 0:
        raise Exception("something went wrong")
    gui.update("some info")
```

The thread can be started using `thread.start_new_thread(function, args[, kwargs])` from the standard library. See the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#module-thread).

Comment: Thanks Constantinius, I'll check that out!

Comment: Constantinius thanks to your input I have a full example here:  http://pastebin.com/AD0UAuMS   it would be great if you included it in your answer.